# How to modify my macro to Allow user to copy past row in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that disable some row based on the value of others row , witch is working fine

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call SecurityColumnsLookup(Target)
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call SecurityColumnsLookup(Target)
End Sub
Private Sub SecurityColumnsLookup(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo MyErr
    Err.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Application.EnableEvents = False
 Select Case Range("V" & (Target.Row)).Value
   //do stuff


    End Select
 ActiveSheet.Protect
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
MyErr:
    On Error Resume Next
 ActiveSheet.Protect
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End Sub
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Call SecurityColumnsLookup(Target)
    End Sub
```

What I would like to know is how to add code to my Macro in order to allow user to copy and past rows , because what is happening right now , is every time I click on unprotected sheet , as soon as I click somewhere else , the macro will re-protect it

Is it possible to enable copy/past feature at any time?

Thank  you

Comment: Is there a worksheet you want to work on, without calling the `SecurityColumnsLookup`? If so, just add something like `If ActiveSheet <> Sheets("whateversheet") Then Call Security...`.  Do you need this to be a worksheet_change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way would just be to check if excel is in cut/copy mode

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Application.CutCopyMode <> xlCopy Or xlCut Then
        Call SecurityColumnsLookup(Target)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work BUT this worked If Application.CutCopyMode <> 1 Or If Application.CutCopyMode <>2 Then
        Call SecurityColumnsLookup(Target)
    End If @sorceri thanks for the tips :)